# How can I plot bar chart in Julia?

Tags: julia, ijulia-notebook

```
plot(Giorni,Fatturato, label="line")
scatter!( Giorni,Fatturato, label="points")
ylabel!("Fatturato [Dollari]")
xlabel!("Tempo (Giorni)")
title!("Fatturato Giornaliero")
```

With this I obtain a normal graph, how can i plot a bar chart?

Answer (score 7):

I guess you are looking for `Plots.bar` function. The code below produces the following plot
[image: barplot fatturato giornaliero]

```
using Plots
giorni = collect(1:10)
fatturato = rand(10)
p = bar(giorni,fatturato)
ylabel!("Fatturato [Dollari]")
xlabel!("Tempo (Giorni)")
title!("Fatturato Giornaliero")
savefig(p,"barplot.png")
```

Answer (score 5):

You can obtain barchart via `bar!` or `histogram!` depending what exactly you want to achieve. For an example:

```
using Plots
giorni = rand(50) .+ (0.8:0.8:40)
fatturato = giorni .+ rand(50)

plot(giorni,fatturato, label="line")
scatter!( giorni,fatturato, label="points")
ylabel!("Fatturato [Dollari]")
xlabel!("Tempo (Giorni)")
title!("Fatturato Giornaliero")
histogram!(giorni,label="giorni",bins=20)
histogram!(fatturato,label="fatturato",bins=20, orientation=:horizontal)
```

It is not clear however what you exactly have in mind so this is just an example.

[image]